# Need some idea on $q.reject in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using interceptor for checking responses, and if there is error I am rejecting the response, which is working fine, but issue is after rejecting response I am getting html file which is not rendering properly, even in html response (from browser console), it is showing html tags but it is not rendering that and displaying blank page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using route provider for switching, where I am hitting to json and getting response.

```
  $routeProvider
.when("/news", {
    templateUrl: "newsView.html",
    controller: "newsController",
    resolve: {
        message: $http.post('xyz.json',{});
    }
}
})
```

Now  my json contains error message, like below:

```
{data:{errorCode:'231',message:'Custom Error'}}
```

After this I have created one interceptor which check if there is error message then it rejects the response else it returns the response.

```
  if(data.errorCode)
  {
   add error code to the custom directive message list
   $q.reject(response)
   }
   return response
```

In my html file I have a custom directive.

```
  <div message></div>
```

Now issue is that I am getting json file with error code and it is getting required data, and after that I am getting html file news.html file which is not rendering the custom directive and if I remove the reject , it is showing custom directive

Comment: and if remove the Sq.reject(response), it is working fine.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's pretty much impossible to guess what your problem might be based on your description.

Comment: @nathan.meadows : I have added code as far as I a remember, because it is in my office laptop and unfortunately i cannot provide exact code now.